# Checkbox Text Not Showing [HTML]

Tags: html

Not sure why my textbox text isn't showing. Any clue?

```
<div id="orderForm">
        <h1> create your own 'za </h1>
        <form name="pizzaOrderForm" action="http://yoda.cs.uwec.edu/CS268/students/HARDTR/processForm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return !!(validatePizzaSize() & validateToppings() & validateTextArea())">
            <table id="formTable">
                <tr>
                    <td id="formLabel">Size:</td>
                    <td><select name="size" id="pizzaSize">
                        <option value="">Choose a size</option>
                        <option value="s">Small</option>
                        <option value="m">Medium</option>
                        <option value="l">Large</option>
                        <option value="r">Ryan Sized</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="formLabel">Toppings:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" value="pep">Pepperoni<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" value="sau">Sausage<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="onion" value="oni">Onion<br>
                            <input id="jalap" type="checkbox" name="jalapeno" value="jal">Jalapeno<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="greenpep" value="gp">Green Pepper<br>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="formLabel">Comments:</td>
                    <td>
                    <textarea id="textAreaComment"  name="comments" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form name="submit">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order"><br>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is a picture: [image]

Edit: source code: http://pastebin.com/6Xm75RgS

Comment: can you please add the code for your page, we can't really help much from a screenshot.

Comment: @Ben http://pastebin.com/6Xm75RgS

Comment: The html seems to work fine for me, do you have any css or other code?

Comment: @Ben Oh... is it the CSS? Here's my CSS code: http://pastebin.com/FbR94kFz

Comment: still works with css, maybe you can show example?

Comment: i believe the problem is black text on a black background, please see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Added `<span style="color:#FFF">` and it worked

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" value="pep"><span style="color:#FFF">Pepperoni</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="sausage" value="sau"><span style="color:#FFF">Sausage</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="onion" value="oni"><span style="color:#FFF">Onion</span><br>
<input id="jalap" type="checkbox" name="jalapeno" value="jal"><span style="color:#FFF">Jalapeno</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="greenpep" value="gp"><span style="color:#FFF">Green Pepper</span><br>
```

**OR** just add `style="color:#FFF"` at the `<td>`

```
<td style="color:#FFF">
 <input  type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" value="pep"> Pepperoni <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" value="sau"> Sausage <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="onion" value="oni"> Onion <br>
 <input id="jalap" type="checkbox" name="jalapeno" value="jal"> Jalapeno <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="greenpep" value="gp"> Green Pepper <br>
</td>
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" id="id_of_checkbox" value="value">
<label for="id_of_checkbox">Text</label>
```

This way the checkbox will also be checked/unchecked by clicking the label

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below code in your html

```
<td>
  <select name="size" id="pizzaSize">
    <option value="">Choose a size</option>
    <option value="s">Small</option>
    <option value="m">Medium</option>
    <option value="l">Large</option>
    <option value="r">Ryan Sized</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Replace with this code

```
 <td style="color:#fff;">
  <select name="size" id="pizzaSize">
    <option value="">Choose a size</option>
    <option value="s">Small</option>
    <option value="m">Medium</option>
    <option value="l">Large</option>
    <option value="r">Ryan Sized</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see a textbox in the code? And maybe you can look at the submit `<form>` you open in the middle of your table. That could give trouble.

Comment: @Ben This answer is quite on the mark. Nobody else mentioned the nested <form>!

Comment: @Mr Lister obviously you are very much more experienced than myself but i thought you were only supposed to post answer which fixed the problem, removing the nested form didnt fix the problem. So it is a suggestion at best, not a detailed answer, no code etc & should be made in the comments

Comment: @Ben True, true. Maybe it would have been better off as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have supplied results in black text on a black background.

The text is there if you try to select it but it is ignoring your `color: #ffffff;`

if you wrap your text in label tags you will then be able to style them better e.g.

```
<label>Text</label>
```

then in your stylesheet

```
label{
  color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Check-boxes have been displayed you just haven't labeled them. Use the Label tag to specify what each label stands for. 
for example:

```html
<label>Check_BoxName</label><input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox_val" name="Checkbox_name" />
```